# Problema (Same Origin Policy) utilizando Vue.js e CouchDB

Tags: vue.js, cors, couchdb, vue-resource

Estou fazendo uma requisição de post através do resource do **Vue.js**, para criar um documento no **CouchDB**, habilitei o o cors no couchdb com *, deixei o banco habilitado para o ususario admin e fiz o seguinte código:

```
  var csrfmiddlewaretoken = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value;
  var cred_ = btoa('admin:admin')

  var form:{
    nome:"Fulano"
  }
  this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5984/formulario/data
    form,
    {headers:{
      "X-CSRFToken":csrfmiddlewaretoken,
      "Authorization":"Basic "+cred_,
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  });
```

O seguinte erro é apresentado:

> A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do
>   recurso remoto em...

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido lendo a documentação do couchdb, estava aplicando o metodo errado, ficou assim o codigo certo.

var cred_ = btoa('admin:admin')

var form:{
    nome:"Fulano"
  }
  this.$http.put('http://127.0.0.1:5984/formulario/data
    form,
    {headers:{
      "Authorization":"Basic "+cred_,
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  });